# android pass json to HashMap to llistview shown in alertdialog

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i need to get 2 columns from mysql database so I pass them in HashMap then show them in listview on the alertdialog but I got errors that I can't solve

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sucess;
    try {


        List<NameValuePair> Ext = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Ext.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NotificationID", NotificationID));
        json3 = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(Get_Ext,"POST", Ext);
        //json3 = jsonParser2.getJSONFromUrl(Get_Ext);
        //getExt = json3.getString("FieldTitle");
        //getExtVal=json3.getString("FieldValue");
        Rec2 = new JSONArray(getExt);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        for(int i = 0; i < Rec2.length(); i++){

        JSONObject c = Rec2.getJSONObject(i);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("FieldTitle", c.getString("FieldTitle"));

        map.put("FieldValue", c.getString("FieldValue"));

        MyArrList.add(map);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    return null ;
}
```

here my onpostexecute :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String st){


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "done" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    SimpleAdapter ExtAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), MyArrList, R.layout.extended_message, new String[]{"FieldTitle","FieldValue"}, new int[]{R.id.ExtTitle, R.id.ExtMessage}); 
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Notifications.this);
    LayoutInflater inflat = getLayoutInflater();
    View turnview = (View) inflat.inflate(R.layout.extended_list, null);
    alertDialogBuilder2.setView(turnview);
    alertDialogBuilder2.setTitle("Call for Action ...");
    Extlist = (ListView) turnview.findViewById(R.id.extendedlst);
    Extlist.setAdapter(ExtAdpt);
    alertDialogBuilder2.create();
    alertDialogBuilder2.show();
```

}

I had tested my php file on browser and it works well

My logcat

```
03-10 18:35:23.048: W/dalvikvm(1720): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.example.notifier.Notifications$GetExtended.onPostExecute(Notifications.java:492)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.example.notifier.Notifications$GetExtended.onPostExecute(Notifications.java:1)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-10 18:35:23.088: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me :'(

The whole code:

```
package com.example.notifier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.internal.ParentDriveIdSet;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Notifications extends Activity {

    Spinner tiFi , ty ;
    ProgressDialog progs;
    Button sh ;
    SqlCommands sql;
    String[] Fields , name , name2, name3;
    SimpleCursorAdapter Adpt ;
    ListView NotiLst , Extlist;
    ImageView Hip, Ntype , arr ;
    String getGrp_url = "http:///db_get_grp.php";
    String Get_Ext = "http:///get_Extended.php";
    String result , fld, bdy ,NotificationID , getExt , getExtVal;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONParser jsonParser2 = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = null ;
    JSONObject json3 = null ;
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_Rec = "Grp_Name";
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
    JSONArray Rec = null;
    JSONArray Rec2 = null;
    JSONArray Rec3 = null;

    final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            tiFi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timFilt);
            ty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typFilt);      
           NotiLst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.msgListView);
           Hip =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
           Ntype =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Prio);
           sh =(Button) findViewById(R.id.dbadd);
            Extlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.extendedlst);    

          new GetGroup().execute();


    sh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*      sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
                    Boolean x = sql.AddEntry(2,"aaaa","fggdfg",2,3,3,"2016-03-07");
                    if (x==true){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    CusListView();*/

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  NotificationID , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                });




    /* tiFi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:


                break;

            default:
                break;
            }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
         */       



    /*    
   arr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor c = sql.GetData();


        }
    });  
     */
      NotiLst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
                Cursor cr = (Cursor) NotiLst.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Cursor cr = sql.gettype((int) id);
                if (cr.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    fld = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Types"));}

                switch (fld) {
                case "1":

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Notifications.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Message");
                      if (cr.moveToFirst()) 
                    {
                    bdy = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Body"));} 
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(bdy);
                    alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialogBuilder.show();
                    break;

                case "2":

                      if (cr.moveToFirst()) 
                    {
                    NotificationID = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("NotificationID"));
                    }   
                     new GetExtended().execute();  

                    break;
                }

                        }});




    String[] items = new String[]{"Ever", "Today", "Yseterday", "Last Week" , "Last Month" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> timAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
   tiFi.setAdapter(timAdpt);
   tiFi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
        String[] mFields = new String[]{SqlCommands.Subject, SqlCommands.Body, SqlCommands.DateTime};
        int [] tview = new int []{R.id.sbj,R.id.bdy,R.id.DT};
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            String d = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            Cursor c = sql.getDate(d)  ;
            SimpleCursorAdapter Dadpt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c , mFields, tview ,0 );
            Dadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            NotiLst.setAdapter(Dadpt);

            break;
        case 2:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            String d1 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            Cursor c1 = sql.getDate(d1)  ;
            SimpleCursorAdapter Dadpt1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c1 , mFields, tview ,0 );
            Dadpt1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            NotiLst.setAdapter(Dadpt1);
            break;
        case 3:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            String d2 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            Cursor c2 = sql.getDateweek(d2)  ;
            SimpleCursorAdapter Dadpt2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c2 , mFields, tview ,0 );
            Dadpt2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            NotiLst.setAdapter(Dadpt2);
            break;
        case 4:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
            String d3 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            Cursor c3 = sql.getDate(d3)  ;
            SimpleCursorAdapter Dadpt3 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c3 , mFields, tview ,0 );
            Dadpt3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            NotiLst.setAdapter(Dadpt3);
            break;

        default:
            CusListView();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


}


public void spin(){
        ArrayAdapter<String> grpAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, name);

        ty.setAdapter(grpAdpt);
        ty.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                CusListView();
                break;

            default:
                sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
                Fields = new String[]{SqlCommands.Subject, SqlCommands.Body, SqlCommands.DateTime};
                int [] Dview = new int []{R.id.sbj,R.id.bdy,R.id.DT};
                //int P = (int)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Cursor c = sql.getSpecificData(position)  ;
                SimpleCursorAdapter Adpt2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c , Fields, Dview ,0 );
                Adpt2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                NotiLst.setAdapter(Adpt2);
                break;
            } 


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }}); }





@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void CusListView(){
sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());
Fields = new String[]{SqlCommands.Subject, SqlCommands.Body, SqlCommands.DateTime};
int [] Dview = new int []{R.id.sbj,R.id.bdy,R.id.DT};
Cursor c = sql.GetData();
Adpt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.items, c , Fields, Dview ,0 );
NotiLst.setAdapter(Adpt);

}

private void IsHigh(){
sql = new SqlCommands(getApplicationContext());

Cursor c = sql.GetData();
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
 do {
     int IShig = c.getColumnIndex("Priopity");
     if(IShig!=1){
     Hip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
     }
     else {
         Hip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
     }
 } while (c.moveToNext());
}
sql.close();


}

public void showSpinner(){

    try {

    JSONObject json; 
    Rec = new JSONArray(result);
    name = new String[Rec.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<Rec.length();i++){

    json = Rec.getJSONObject(i);
    name[i] = json.getString("Grp_Name");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
    list1.add(name[i]);
    }

    spin();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   


class GetGroup extends AsyncTask<String, String, String >{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{

             json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getGrp_url);

             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
             result = json.getString("Grp_Name");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            showSpinner();

        }

}

class GetExtended extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sucess;
        try {


            List<NameValuePair> Ext = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Ext.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NotificationID", NotificationID));
            json3 = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(Get_Ext,"POST", Ext);
            //json3 = jsonParser2.getJSONFromUrl(Get_Ext);
            //getExt = json3.getString("FieldTitle");
            //getExtVal=json3.getString("FieldValue");
            Rec2 = new JSONArray();
            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;
            for(int i = 0; i < Rec2.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = Rec2.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("FieldTitle", c.getString("FieldTitle"));

            map.put("FieldValue", c.getString("FieldValue"));

            MyArrList.add(map);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


        return null ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String st){


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "done" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SimpleAdapter ExtAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), MyArrList, R.layout.extended_message, new String[]{"FieldTitle","FieldValue"}, new int[]{R.id.ExtTitle, R.id.ExtMessage}); 
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Notifications.this);
        LayoutInflater inflat = getLayoutInflater();
        View turnview = (View) inflat.inflate(R.layout.extended_list, null);
        alertDialogBuilder2.setView(turnview);
        alertDialogBuilder2.setTitle("Call for Action ...");
        Extlist = (ListView) turnview.findViewById(R.id.extendedlst);
        Extlist.setAdapter(ExtAdpt);
        alertDialogBuilder2.create();
        alertDialogBuilder2.show();
}
}           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MyArrList seems to be local object of doInBackground method, neither you are returning from doInBackground method. Or you are trying to access that object in onPostExecute, which is null or doesn't exit.

Comment: I declare it on the main class but still getting the same error, could u suggest what should I do?

Comment: As you got NP, seems to be you haven't initialize that global array i.e. you haven't passed the result from doInBackground method to global array, and you are using it. That's why you got NP.

Comment: either remove         final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 from oInBackground method.

Comment: so if I do where should I put it? .... or how to pass it global ... really I'm new to android development

Comment: simple remove final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); from doInBackground method.

Comment: if that doesn't solve the issue post your whole class code.

Comment: no it doesn't solve it ....  I think the problem is in 
Rec2 = new JSONArray() ...  I think I should pass here something () but I don't know what to put there.

Comment: without the whole active code, won't be able to help you.

Comment: I post it now .. in the main post

Comment: Your updated class seems fines to me, is it still showing NP?

Comment: post your SimpleAdapter class